# Problem opening file selector in Safari using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

I'm facing an issue when trying to open a file selector in a reactjs project. The code works well in most browsers, but I'm having difficulties in Safari.

I basically have a button that calls a `selectFile` function.

```
const selectFile = () => {
   const input = document.createElement('input');
   input.type = 'file';
   input.multiple = true;
   input.click();

   input.onchange = () => {
     const filesInput = input.files;
     const filesArray = Array.from(filesInput);

     const filesPreUpload = filesArray.map(file => ({
       file,
       id: uuidv4(),
     }));

   setSelectedFiles(filesPreUpload);
   };
};
```

Sometimes the first click won't work and it won't call the function itself, not opening the file selector. The button is being rendered ONLY if the function exists, so I'm not sure whats happening.
The error happened on both versions 16.6 and 16.5.1.